# Dynamic Table Layout with positioning - firefox bug?

Tags: css, html

Firefox only! Im using absolute positioned tables that have a header, body and footer. When the headers or footers height are dynamically altered, the var element in the middle/body cell must conform to the cells height. This all works initially without dynamic change, but when changed the inner var looses its height:100% ability. Funnt thing tho: when i move the positional css to the tables parent node it works fine.

Here is a [demo](http://vdcsa.ranworx.com/test.php)

Here is the code:

```
<!-- WRONG result -->
<!-- Parent does not hold positional css -->
<div style="">
<table style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:100px;height:300px;width:300px;background:black">
<tr><td style="height:1%;color:#FFF" onclick="this.innerHTML+=this.innerHTML">Click Me!<br></td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding:0px;background:green">
<var style="height:100%;width:100%;display:block;background:red">With style.position set on table.<br><br>Once table cells height are dynamically altered, this var element (or div) looses its ability to measure height:100%</var>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height:20px;color:#FFF" onclick="this.innerHTML+=this.innerHTML">Click Me!<br></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<!-- RIGHT result -->
<!-- Parent holds positional css -->
<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:500px;">
<table style="height:300px;width:300px;background:black">
<tr><td style="height:1%;color:#FFF" onclick="this.innerHTML+=this.innerHTML">Click Me!<br></td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding:0px;background:green">
<var style="height:100%;width:100%;display:block;background:red">With style.position set on table.parentNode<br><br>This one behaves how i expect it to</var>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height:20px;color:#FFF" onclick="this.innerHTML+=this.innerHTML">Click Me!<br></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome are smarter than others browser, but doesn't mean others are bugged (I'm not talking about IE, ok?). Chrome just cover some bug or other for you, Google Way.

When you treat a table markup like a div, img, or some others, it tends to act the same way than them.

So here we are retrieving one of its properties:

I just switch the `display:block` to `display:table` in the child (`<var>`)

```
<!-- LEFT result -->
<div style="">
<table style="position:absolute;top:200px;left:100px;height:300px;width:300px;background:black">
<tr><td style="height:1%;color:#FFF" onclick="this.innerHTML+=this.innerHTML">Click Me!<br></td></tr>
<tr><td style="padding:0px;background:green">
<var style="height:100%;width:100%;display:table;background:red">With style.position set on table.<br><br>Once table cells height are dynamically altered, this var element (or div) looses its ability to measure height:100%</var>
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height:20px;color:#FFF" onclick="this.innerHTML+=this.innerHTML">Click Me!<br></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it worked!! Haha... Is this the recommended / safe way to deal with this problem or is it an exploit or hack?

Comment: Its safe. But i don't know about using it on IE 6 xD